# Will my present identity as Dheeraj survive after Moksha?

Tags: philosophy, moksha

Everyone takes birth and dies and then takes rebirth or attains moksha.
My question is: Will I as Dheeraj survive after attaining moksha? Will I be able to remember myself as Dheeraj in the past? After attaining moksha, will I be able to remember the good and bad deeds I did as Dheeraj ?

Comment: Moksha by definition liberates you from all Karma, where is the question of good and bad

Comment: @Akhil Moksha will liberate me from all karma but will I remember the karma done by Dheeraj in past ?

Comment: Yes and No, When you are "liberated" then you realize there "Dheeraj" is an illusion, "ego/self" is destroyed completely, You realize everything is you including the rocks, animals, planets etc. In the space of "superconsciousness" you have access to "everything".

Comment: You will be able to remember your karma done as dheeraj "also", but you took innumerable such janmas in lakhs of yonis even as mosquitos, doing many of the same karmas in same yonis. You will remember all of them. This will give you the perspective 'all this' was just your own role in play/leela of the creation leela.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you are a follower of the advaita, or the visistadvaita, or the dvaita. You need to be more specific in your question as presently your question is too broad. Please edit your question as to which school you are asking...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda please answer according to your school.

Answer (score 1):

Dheeraj Verma, who is Dheeraj Verma??? Your seprate entity will reamin intact even after this birth or attaining moksha only if there is such a thing. Now please investigate what is it really which you call Dheeraj Verma. Is it the body then where in it is Dheeraj Verma, all the body is just a bunch of individual cells, bones etc. So the body which we call ours is just a host to approximately 75 trillion cells which are all dead within 6 months and are reborn again so in a way the body which we call ours goes through cycles of death and rebirth within 6 months but we do not die with it. So what exactly do you mean by Dheeraj Verma, its just a name afterall but what does it represents. Try to figure out be concious of your I when you try to describe it with this or that and investigate are you really that which you are describing yourself as? THANK YOU. NAMASTE.